# Not able to generate ARM template

Tags: azure-rm-template, azure-adf

Generating ARM templates
Failed to save Arm Templates. Error: {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"The path '/ARMTemplateForFactory.json' specified in the add operation already exists. Please specify a new path.\r\nParameter name: newPush","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebServer.InvalidArgumentValueException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebServer, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=","typeKey":"InvalidArgumentValueException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}

Publish from master to adf_publish is successful, but failing to generate ARM template. How do I resolve this to generate ARM template successfully.